# Designing inter-objects interactions modifiable without modifying the objects' code

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

Assume we're in Unity's environment.

Assume we've got PlayerA object and PlayerB object. PlayerA wants to deal damage (i.e. lower the health variable of PlayerB).

I'm looking to design an interaction system that will allow to modify what happens if PlayerA signals his intent to deal X damage to PlayerB, and it will allow to make the modification without modifying PlayerA's or PlayerB's code.

In short, once the amount of player effects stacks up, I do not want the DealDamage function to have dozens of if(hasArmorEffect), if(isImmuneEffect), if(hasDamageReflectionEffect) checks that will check for all this stuff. Ideally, the system would work in such a way that the programmer can write the Armor component, hook it into somewhere to signal he's interested in DealDamage calculations and attach it to the GameObject, without modifying A and B code.

Comment: Read [Wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) by Eric Lippert. It's a five-parts blog post describing in details a related problem you're most likely will be dealing with and how to solve it.

Comment: Specifically, [part three](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/04/wizards-and-warriors-part-three/) of said series deals with something very similar to what you've described in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with a modifier list. Suppose you have the interfaces:

```
public interface IHealth
{
    float Health {get};
    void TakeDamage(float damage);
}

public interface IDamageModifier
{
   float Apply(float damage);
}
```

Now lets make some modifier implementations:

```
public class ShieldModifier : ScriptableObject, IDamageModifier
{
    private float shieldAmount = 10;

    public float Apply(float damage)
    {
        var actualDamage = Mathf.Max(0, damage - this.shieldAmount)

        return actualDamage;
    }
}

public class InvulnerabilityModifier: ScriptableObject, IDamageModifier
{
    public float Apply(float damage)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Finally your enemy would have a list of modifiers:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour, IHealth
{
    public float Health {get; private set;}
    public List<IDamageModifier> modifiers; // Pretend this has both modifiers above.

    public void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        var actualDamage = damage;

        foreach(var mod in this.modifiers)
        {
            actualDamage = mod.Apply(actualDamage);
        }

        this.Health -= actualDamage; // 0 because of Invulnerability
    }
}
```

So if your enemy has a shield modifier with a shield value of 10, then an attack of 50 damage would only inflict 40 damage.

Your modifiers can be scriptable objects if you want them to be configurable through the inspector.

This approach is pretty rudimentary. For an effect like `ReflectDamageModifier` your modifier interface may need to take an `IHealth attacker` for example:

```
public class ReflectDamageModifier: IDamageModifier
{
    private float reflectionFactor = 0.5; // Reflect 50% of damage

    public float Apply(float damage, IHealth attacker)
    {
        attacker.TakeDamage(damage * this.reflectionFactor);

        return damage;
    }
}
```

This approach is vulnerable to the order of modifiers though. For example, if you put the reflect modifier first, it will reflect more damage than putting it last. You might need to expand the system with a priority/ordering system for example.

This reflection modifier is also vulnerable to a stackoverflow exception if both the attacker and the target has a reflection modifier, so just watch out for that.

Hope this helps.